# I want my recyclerview to show limited cards through condition but all items keep getting shown

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to show a Recyclerview list of jobs that are not finished (`!isJob_finished()`) but every item seems to be shown in the recyclerview card list. How do I make it that when a job is not finished it shall not be shown in recyclerview list?

MY ADAPTER
The adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    //Make a context and iterable datalist variable
    Context context;
    ArrayList<JobModel> userArrayList;

    //Constructor
    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JobModel> userArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Here is where you attach your item layout ie: job_openings_list
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.job_openings_list,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Instantiate your model class to hold the data of the model ur simulating
        JobModel job = userArrayList.get(position);

        //Based on the widgets u used on myViewHolder
        if(job.isJob_finished()==false){
            holder.tv_provided_title.setText(job.getJob_title());
            holder.tv_provided_payout.setText(job.getJob_payout());
            holder.tv_provided_id.setText(job.getJob_ID());

            //OnClickers redirect to intent
            holder.tv_provided_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { ToDescription(v, job); }
            });
            holder.tv_provided_payout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { ToDescription(v, job); }
            });
            holder.tv_provided_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { ToDescription(v, job); }
            });
        }else{

        }

    }

    private void ToDescription(View v, JobModel job) {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), JobDescription.class);
        i.putExtra("job_id",job.getJob_ID());
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Here in scope instantiate the widgets used based on your item layout
        TextView tv_provided_title,tv_provided_payout, tv_provided_id;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //find the widgets
            tv_provided_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provided_title);
            tv_provided_payout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provided_payout);
            tv_provided_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_provided_id);
        }
    }
}
```

MY MODEL
model i am using with the adapter

```
public class JobModel {
    private String Job_title;
    private String Job_ID;
    private String Job_payout;
    private Boolean Job_finished = false;

    private JobModel(){
    }

    public JobModel(String job_title, String job_ID, String job_payout) {
        Job_title = job_title;
        Job_ID = job_ID;
        Job_payout = job_payout;
    }

    public Boolean isJob_finished() { return Job_finished; }

    public void setFinished(Boolean finished) { this.Job_finished = finished; }

    public String getJob_title() {
        return Job_title;
    }

    public void setJob_title(String job_title) {
        Job_title = job_title;
    }

    public String getJob_ID() {
        return Job_ID;
    }

    public void setJob_ID(String job_ID) {
        Job_ID = job_ID;
    }

    public String getJob_payout() {
        return Job_payout;
    }

    public void setJob_payout(String job_payout) {
        Job_payout = job_payout;
    }
}
```

The Code I use is JAVA

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` is a `View`, is intended to show passed data (in this case: using adapter). you should pass already filtered list to adapter instead of whole array with all jobs. thats the simplest way

another, more flexible way is to [implement `Filterable` in adapter](https://www.11zon.com/zon/android/android-recyclerview-adapter-filterable.php) and use filtering, if on start there should be only non-finished jobs then just set filter at the beginning in adapters constructor. you may also introduce some switch/toggle GUI element which will hide/reveal finished jobs (e.g. on `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`)

Comment: I think `Filterable` is a good option, but when using `switch`, it will hide the views?

Comment: you may implement whatever filtering you want. you may pass just `boolean`, you may pass `String` for filtering. thats your choice (as its your implementation inside adapter). `switch` `case` will do job for some limited options, take a look on linked tutorial how its implemented

Comment: I didn't use filterable but you gave me an idea similar to filterable when you mentioned recyclerview is just a view. I 'm edited the documentsnapshot to include a condition in the activity class and it worked. The finished jobs don't show up.

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!